# Can i submit an app with IAP and iAds while tax info is getting reviewed?

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, iad

I am planning on launching my first personal app in the next 2 weeks.

**My app is free, but will contain IAPs and iAds.** I filled out the tax documentation and will have it shipped out to Apple this week. Right now the contract status for both paid apps, and iAds is under "Processing" on iTunes.

1. Will I be able to test IAP until Apple accepts my forms?
2. If so, will i be able to publish to the app store? I don't mind if my earned income just stays with Apple until my forms are approved.

Thanks

Comment: Can you actually set up IAPs without correct banking / tax info?

Comment: I was not able to set up IAPs. I tried but kept receiving my product IDs as invalid. Although this can be due to many reason, i think taxes may be one of them.

Comment: Well so it does not work without adding tax info. there you have your info. you're welcome

Comment: As mentioned, this could have been due to multiple reasons. A confirmation is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't test IAP until Apple accepts your forms. So, wait for Apple to accept all forms, But, as per my experience, it will not take much time from Apple to accept all information.